# Swift 3 not returning any values after successful Facebook login? in iOS 9 and 10

Tags: ios, swift, callback, swift3, facebook-login

I am new to Swift and implementing login through Facebook, after getting successful login app authorisation screen comes after that no callback I am getting, if I pressed OK.

```
 let loginManager = LoginManager()
 loginManager.logIn([.publicProfile,], viewController: self) { (LoginResult) in
            switch LoginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
                loginManager.logOut();
            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                print("Logged in!")
                print("The current value: \(grantedPermissions) \(declinedPermissions), \(accessToken)")
            }

        } 
}
```

Below are logs which I am getting:

> objc[50512]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x11ea25910) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x11e84f210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   2016-11-12 12:10:42.434233 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378404] subsystem:
>   com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0,
>   persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2,
>   enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:10:42.438448
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378404] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category:
>   HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0,
>   info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1,
>   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:10:42.454325
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378391] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard,
>   category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0,
>   info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0,
>   privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:10:42.473882
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category:
>   StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0,
>   info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1,
>   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:10:42.555878
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] subsystem:
>   com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1,
>   persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0,
>   enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:30.658276
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category:
>   Touch, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0,
>   debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1,
>   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:30.660848
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category:
>   Gesture, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl:
>   0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1,
>   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:30.663465
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category:
>   GestureEnvironment, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1,
>   info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1,
>   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:30.663932
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category:
>   GestureExclusion, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1,
>   info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1,
>   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:33.283
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] -canOpenURL: failed for URL:
>   "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus
>   error -10814.)" 2016-11-12 12:11:33.394927
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] subsystem: com.apple.securityd,
>   category: OSStatus, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0,
>   info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0,
>   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:33.396
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] -canOpenURL: failed for URL:
>   "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus
>   error -10814.)" 2016-11-12 12:11:34.306619
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] subsystem: com.apple.siri, category:
>   Intents, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 1, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl:
>   0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0,
>   privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:34.374102
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379295] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category:
>   ViewServicesRDAR22970009, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0,
>   default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0,
>   enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2016-11-12 12:11:34.380188 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] [MC] System
>   group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path
>   is
>   /Users/sanojkashyap/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5D5D2E1B-C389-4941-97E3-B44D2A643AEA/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2016-11-12 12:11:34.417010 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] [MC] Reading
>   from private effective user settings. 2016-11-12 12:11:34.490624
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] subsystem:
>   com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: Observer, enable_level:
>   1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0,
>   enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:34.490995
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] subsystem:
>   com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: Workspace, enable_level:
>   1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0,
>   enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:34.491264
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] subsystem:
>   com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: Trace, enable_level: 1,
>   persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0,
>   enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:45.384320
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2378316] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit
>   handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
>   2016-11-12 12:11:49.003963 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] subsystem:
>   com.apple.libsqlite3, category: logging, enable_level: 0,
>   persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2,
>   enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:49.095066
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] subsystem: com.apple.network, category:
>   , enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0,
>   debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0,
>   privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:49.095426
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 1
>   graph.facebook.com 443 2016-11-12 12:11:49.095974
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] tcp_connection_start 1 starting
>   2016-11-12 12:11:49.096332 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_connection_create creating connection to graph.facebook.com:443
>   2016-11-12 12:11:49.096688 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   tcp_connection_start starting tc_nwconn=0x7f82f1e09b70 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.097035 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   __nw_connection_start_block_invoke 1 starting 2016-11-12 12:11:49.097355 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_handler_start [1 graph.facebook.com:443 initial path
>   (null)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.097584 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443 initial path
>   (null)] reported event path:start 2016-11-12 12:11:49.098597
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [1
>   graph.facebook.com:443 waiting path (satisfied)] 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.098852 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443 waiting path
>   (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied 2016-11-12 12:11:49.099128
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1
>   graph.facebook.com:443 waiting path (satisfied)] skipping state update
>   2016-11-12 12:11:49.099511 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_proxy_handler_should_use_proxy Looking up proxy for
>   hostname: graph.facebook.com, ifindex: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:49.100494
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] subsystem:
>   com.apple.SystemConfiguration, category: SCPreferences, enable_level:
>   0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2,
>   enable_private_data: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:49.101720
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_resolver
>   startWithHandler:] [1 graph.facebook.com:443 waiting resolver
>   (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.102061 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428]
>   [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443 in_progress
>   resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:start_dns 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.102633 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue Starting host resolution
>   graph.facebook.com:443, flags 0x4000d000 2016-11-12 12:11:49.103126
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback
>   flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoSuchRecord(-65554)
>   hostname=graph.facebook.com. addr=::.0 ttl=60 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.258313 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0)
>   hostname=star.c10r.facebook.com. addr=31.13.78.13:0 ttl=17 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.259098 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1 graph.facebook.com:443 in_progress
>   resolver (satisfied)] resolver is complete 2016-11-12 12:11:49.259517
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1
>   graph.facebook.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Adding
>   endpoint handler for 31.13.78.13:443 2016-11-12 12:11:49.260324
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_update [1
>   graph.facebook.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] Updated
>   endpoint list is (31.13.78.13:443) 2016-11-12 12:11:49.261117
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1
>   graph.facebook.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported
>   event resolver:receive_dns 2016-11-12 12:11:49.261804
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [1 graph.facebook.com:443
>   in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting child endpoint
>   31.13.78.13:443 2016-11-12 12:11:49.262284 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too
>   small, received 24, expected 28 2016-11-12 12:11:49.262817
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [1 graph.facebook.com:443
>   in_progress resolver (satisfied)] starting next child endpoint in
>   250ms 2016-11-12 12:11:49.263283 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_handler_start [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 initial path (null)]
>   2016-11-12 12:11:49.263696 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443
>   in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 initial path (null)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.263931 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 initial path (null)] reported event path:start 2016-11-12 12:11:49.264577 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 waiting path
>   (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.265134 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428]
>   [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443
>   in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 waiting path (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.265523 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied 2016-11-12 12:11:49.265779
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_proxy_handler_should_use_proxy Looking up proxy for
>   hostname: , ifindex: 0 2016-11-12 12:11:49.266631
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow
>   startWithHandler:] [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 waiting socket-flow
>   (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.266864 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428]
>   [] nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 in_progress
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] creating socket 2016-11-12 12:11:49.267216
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols
>   [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.268621 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   ____nwlog_simulate_crash_inner_block_invoke dlopen CrashReporterSupport failed 2016-11-12 12:11:49.268876
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate
>   crash failed "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK
>   failed: [42] Protocol not available" 2016-11-12 12:11:49.269559
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts
>   setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping
>   backtrace:
>           [x86_64] libnetcore-856.1.8
>       0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x00000001137ea80e __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
>       1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000113ac7194 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3002
>       2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000113aa4db8 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
>       3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000113aa3dd5 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
>       4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000113aa2b34 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
>       5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000113abdd11 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
>       6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000113abd740 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
>       7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000113ad5003 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
>       8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000 2016-11-12 12:11:49.270136 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 in_progress
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Attached flow protocol 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.270457 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443
>   in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.270864 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 in_progress
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.514401 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child [1 graph.facebook.com:443
>   in_progress resolver (satisfied)] no child at index 1 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.624883 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x800 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.625164 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received CONNECTED event
>   2016-11-12 12:11:49.625398 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_socket_setup_notsent_lowat Set TCP_NOTSENT_LOWAT(16384) 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.625747 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 in_progress
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.626726 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.626925
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Connected path is satisfied 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.627331 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443
>   in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.627565 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow
>   (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.628130 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443 ready resolver
>   (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.628371 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443 ready
>   resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.628838
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:changed_viability 2016-11-12 12:11:49.629183
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1
>   graph.facebook.com:443 ready resolver (satisfied)] reported event
>   flow:changed_viability 2016-11-12 12:11:49.629588
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379295] [] __tcp_connection_start_block_invoke
>   1 sending event TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_CONNECTED in response to state
>   ready and error (null) 2016-11-12 12:11:49.629811
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379295] [] tcp_connection_event_notify 1 event:
>   TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_CONNECTED, reason: nw_connection event, should
>   deliver: true 2016-11-12 12:11:49.630560
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_start_tls_while_connected [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.630921
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_start_tls_while_connected [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Using CoreTLS 2016-11-12 12:11:49.631390
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_start_tls_while_connected [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Set custom TLS client queue 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.631758 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_start_tls_while_connected [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Set custom TLS prepare handler 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.632001 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_start_tls_while_connected [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Set custom TLS message handler 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.632435 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_start_tls_while_connected [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Attached TLS protocol to connected flow
>   2016-11-12 12:11:49.632670 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443 ready
>   resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1 31.13.78.13:443
>   in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.633067
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_secondary_connect 2016-11-12 12:11:49.633367
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1
>   graph.facebook.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported
>   event flow:start_secondary_connect 2016-11-12 12:11:49.633594
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] [] nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report
>   [1 graph.facebook.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received
>   child report:[1.1 31.13.78.13:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)]
>   2016-11-12 12:11:49.633988 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 in_progress
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.634294 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443 in_progress
>   resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.634715 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 in_progress
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Transport protocol connected 2016-11-12
>   12:11:49.634998 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443
>   in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:49.635374 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 in_progress
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_transport
>   2016-11-12 12:11:49.635638 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379428] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443 in_progress
>   resolver (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_transport 2016-11-12
>   12:11:50.252277 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379295] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 in_progress
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected 2016-11-12
>   12:11:50.254307 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379295] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:50.254741
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379295] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready
>   socket-flow (satisfied)] Connected path is satisfied 2016-11-12
>   12:11:50.255445 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379295] []
>   nw_endpoint_resolver_receive_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443
>   in_progress resolver (satisfied)] received child report:[1.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:50.255888 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379295] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow
>   (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect 2016-11-12
>   12:11:50.256238 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379295] []
>   nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 graph.facebook.com:443 ready resolver
>   (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect 2016-11-12
>   12:11:50.256699 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379740] []
>   __tcp_connection_start_block_invoke 1 sending event TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_TLS_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE in response to state ready
>   and error (null) 2016-11-12 12:11:50.257009
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379740] [] tcp_connection_event_notify 1 event:
>   TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_TLS_HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE, reason: nw_connection
>   event, should deliver: true 2016-11-12 12:11:50.257736
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379740] [] tcp_connection_get_statistics DNS:
>   159ms/163ms since start, TCP: 365ms/538ms since start, TLS:
>   623ms/1158ms since start 2016-11-12 12:11:50.691120
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379295] [] tcp_connection_cancel 1 2016-11-12
>   12:11:50.691663 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379755] []
>   nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x4 2016-11-12
>   12:11:50.691895 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379755] []
>   nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received WRITE_CLOSE event
>   2016-11-12 12:11:50.692246 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379755] []
>   nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1 graph.facebook.com:443 ready resolver
>   (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:50.692548 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379755]
>   [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 ready socket-flow
>   (satisfied)] 2016-11-12 12:11:50.693087 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379755]
>   [] __nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke sendmsg(fd 9, 31 bytes):
>   socket has been closed 2016-11-12 12:11:50.693330
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379755] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_error [1.1
>   31.13.78.13:443 cancelled socket-flow (null)] Socket protocol sent error: [32] Broken pipe 2016-11-12 12:11:50.693723
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379755] []
>   nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [1.1 31.13.78.13:443 cancelled
>   socket-flow (null)] Output protocol disconnected 2016-11-12
>   12:11:50.693993 SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379755] []
>   nw_resolver_cancel_on_queue 0x60800011aca0 2016-11-12 12:11:50.694334
>   SKFacebookLogin[50512:2379755] [] -[NWConcrete_tcp_connection dealloc]
>   1

Updated: Getting Logs from SDK

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
```

Screen opens successfully and authorize the app as well, then

[image: This screen comes]

then no success callback.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set your configuration for Facebook if you're receiving no response after login. In a simple example where you have your FB button hooked up to an outlet like this:

`@IBOutlet weak var facebookButton: FBSDKLoginButton!`

I would try creating a function and setting the read permissions (aka the data you're requesting from that users account) and setting the facebookButton delegate equal to self:

`func configureFacebook(){
    facebookButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
    facebookButton.delegate = self
  }`

Then in `viewDidLoad()` :

`override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureFacebook()
  }`

If I understood your problem correctly, I hope this solves it for you!

Answer (score 0):

For now, downgrading to FBSDKCoreKit 4.16.0 instead of 4.17.0 worked for me.  Here's what I have now in my Podfile:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.16.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.16.0'
```